# How to add a listener in a particular cell in a grid in GXT

Tags: grid, listener, gxt

I would like to add a listener when I am clicking the cell for categories only.

this is the declaration of my columnConfig

```
ColumnConfig<UserRights, Boolean> unlockConfig = new ColumnConfig<UserRights, Boolean>(properties.hasUnlock(), 50);
            unlockConfig.setHeader("Unlock");
            cfgs.add(unlockConfig);

            ColumnConfig<UserRights, String> catConfig = new ColumnConfig<UserRights, String>(properties.categories(), 150);
            catConfig.setHeader("Categories");
            cfgs.add(catConfig);
cm = new ColumnModel<UserRights>(cfgs);

            grid = new Grid<UserRights>(store, cm);
            grid.getView().setAutoFill(true);
            grid.addStyleName("margin-10");
            grid.setLayoutData(new VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData(1, 1));
            grid.addRowClickHandler(new RowClickEvent.RowClickHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onRowClick(RowClickEvent event) {
                    index = event.getRowIndex();
                }
            });
rowEditing = new GridRowEditing<UserRights>(grid);
rowEditing.addEditor(unlockConfig, new CheckBox());
```

how could I add a listener in the category column?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in your categories cell that prompts a user to click, it just contains text. What you should be doing is using the columnConfig.setCell(Cell cell) method to specify a cell that contains an interactive component.

You could still try something along these lines:

```
columnConfig.setCell(new SimpleSafeHtmlCell<String>(SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer.getInstance(), "click") {
  @Override
  public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
    if (event.getType().equals("click")) {

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the interaction between Store and your editor.